# Guzzlehttp error when I use coinbase/coinbase php library in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, coinbase-api, guzzle, coinbase-php

Now I am using coinbase/coinbase php library in laravel project. I tried to get accounts using `$client->getAccounts();`, But this gives error like following.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Argument 1 passed to
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Exception\HttpException::exceptionClass() must be an
>   instance of Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, null given, called in
>   core\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\Exception\HttpException.php
>   on line 33

I tried to get error response by checking exception.

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

This code is normal and it was working 1 year ago without any issue.
Is there anyone for this issue?
Thank you for everyone's response here.

Answer (score 0):

Try Uploading to Your online server and retry, it might be an issue with Your localhost.

I have experienced it sometime ago, but still fix, I will just upload to my cPanel and try it in production and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the request is failing as cURL is unable to verify the certificate provided by the server.

You can solve the problem either way -

- Allows curl command to work with “insecure” or “invalid” SSL certificates without https certificates. Use cURL with **-k** option which allows curl to make insecure connections, that is cURL does not verify the certificate.
- Add the root CA (the CA signing the server certificate) to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Using Guzzle: Set verify to false

```
$client->request('GET', 'https://somewebsite.com', ['verify' => false]);
```

Note: It is best to install SSL certificate.